# sort list of lists: inner list(string,tuple,number) descending order of tuple length and ascending order of number

Tags: list

sort based on length of tuple if there is tie then number :

Input is:

```
[['37208', ('identification', 'weight'), 997474747],
 ['43676', ('weight',), 997395833],
 ['41674', ('update',), 997101449],
 ['16139', ('identification',), 996941896],
 ['52265', ('identification',), 996865203],
 ['7836', ('identification',), 996784565],
 ['23922', ('identification',), 996732026],
 ['22663', ('weight',), 995110024],
 ['8366', ('identification',), 994750656],
 ['5764', ('identification',), 994397759],
 ['12575', ('identification',), 990259740],
 ['41025', ('weight',), 977635782],
 ['19563', ('weight',), 945121951],
 ['40243', ('identification', 'weight'), 940246045]]
```

Expected output :

```
[['40243', ('identification', 'weight'), 940246045],
 ['37208', ('identification', 'weight'), 997474747],
 ['19563', ('weight',), 945121951],
 ['41025', ('weight',), 977635782],
 ['12575', ('identification',), 990259740] ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is Python..

You can do something like this:

```
myList.sort(key=lambda elem: (-len(elem[1]), elem[2]))
```

Where we're passing each list into `elem` via the `lambda`, sorting by the length of the tuple `elem[1]` in reverse (highest to lowest) first, then by the int at index 2 in each list.

Output:

```
[['40243', ('identification', 'weight'), 940246045],
 ['37208', ('identification', 'weight'), 997474747],
 ['19563', ('weight',), 945121951],
 ['41025', ('weight',), 977635782],
 ['12575', ('identification',), 990259740],
 ['5764', ('identification',), 994397759],
 ['8366', ('identification',), 994750656],
 ['22663', ('weight',), 995110024],
 ['23922', ('identification',), 996732026],
 ['7836', ('identification',), 996784565],
 ['52265', ('identification',), 996865203],
 ['16139', ('identification',), 996941896],
 ['41674', ('update',), 997101449],
 ['43676', ('weight',), 997395833]]
```

Comment: Thanks RyanHx for time and effort - I solved it other way using function